# How can i set an offset on my Enemy script so he can easy take a shoot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So i have a small code in my 2d game in unity that if my enemy's y position equal to my player's y position, then my Enemy will shoot a bullet, the thing is right now my enemy need exactly position to take a shoot, so is there anyway that i can add and offset to get this easier

```
if (target.position.y == boss.position.y)
        {
            Shoot();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply find the distance between two values by doing `|x - y|`

```
var targetPosition = target.position.y;
var enemyPosition = boss.position.y;
var offSet = 3f;

var shouldShoot = Mathf.Abs(targetPosition - enemyPosition) <= offSet;

if(shouldShoot) {
    Shoot();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i didn't know that mathf.abs will handle this.